# Popup.js shows values from rest api only when inspect view background.js is open

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the background.js, I am getting the rest API URL value from storage, which is being set via the chrome extension options page.

Every 2 minutes the alarm fires in background.js and makes a call to get the response.

The popup.js shows the value of the rest API response on install and then will not show the rest API response after some time. Although, it shows the value and updates it every 2 minutes when the inspect view background page is open without any issue.

Basically, the inspect view background page makes my extension work flawlessly when it's open.

Code ...

[Popup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MDbZwmhq6EF7sPktPbFo3VfDNP5tW66z/view?usp=sharing)

[background](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6gut5DEELddMN0XZCxRmB_U-NADKVBj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Give us some code.

Comment: The behavior is caused by the fact you're using `"persistent": false` in manifest. Either fix your code to not assume the background script is always running as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or switch to `true`.

Comment: That's correct I am using "persistent": false in manifest making it true does resolve the issue but not sure if it's the right way to do it. Adding Code, please take a look.